# Derivative of exponential map $\exp_p v$ respective to vector $v$

Tags: differential-geometry

The question concerns the exponential map. The generic map allows to formalize the concept of polar coordinate by definition of normal coordinate given by coordinate $\gamma(1)$, for given geodesic $\gamma(t)$ with initial conditions $\gamma(0) = p$ and $\gamma'(0) = v$. This said, how can I perform the calculation $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \exp_p v$, for $v \in T_p \mathcal{S}$?

Best regards,
Bruno Peixoto

Comment: Are you referring to $d_v\exp_p(v)$ by $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \exp_p(v)$?

Comment: Since you mention about the former, I suppose it exists. The latter is my attempt to make it work.

Comment: Could you make it clear what you mean by $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \exp_p(v)$?

Comment: Well, the exponential map is supposed to be a function that maps every point on the surrounding of a $p$ based on some direction vector $v$ given on local basis tensor $E$. I wish to find its partial derivative respective to v out.

Comment: So you mean $\frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0} \exp_p(tv)$?

Comment: It sounds very promising. Go on!

Comment: The difference between derivative respective to $t$ and $v$ are: the former verifies the variation along the geodesic and the latter about the nearby geodesic $v+dv$. Therefore, they are not equal!

Comment: Your question is vague. $v$ is not part of any coordinate system, so "$\frac{\partial}{\partial v}$" in itself makes no sense. The map $\exp_p \colon T_pM \to M$ is differentiable, so it has a differential. Besides that, its partial derivative with respect to a vector $v$ is misleading and confusing. I was trying to help you by asking you questions to which you could have answered details, but you seem to think I don't know what I'm talking about.

Comment: Why is v not part of any coordinate system? A surface $\mathcal{S}$ submerged in $\mathbb{R}^3$, for instance, has $v$ in coordinate system written based in $T_p S \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. What did I do wrong?

Comment: You did not specify any coordinate system, did you?

Comment: My apologies. I hope it is clearer than before.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not. This still does not make sense, at least to me. Specifying $v$ is in the tangent space at $p$ does not make it a tangent vector of a coordinates system, neither does it make the question clearer. I suggest that you write carefully what you really mean by $\frac{\partial}{\partial v} \exp_p(v)$, with all details. If you want to find the infinitesimal change of $\exp_p(v + w)$ with $w$ small, what you are looking for is called the differential at $v$ evaluated at $w$ and is denoted $D_v\exp_p(w)$, $d\exp_p(v)\cdot w$... But not with a partial derivative

Comment: Ok, you posed your point. How do I perform the differential at $v$ evaluated at $w$?

Comment: This is a long story involving [Jacobi fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_field) and has already been asked and answered on this site. Shortly, $d_v\exp_p(w)$ is the value at time $1$ of the unique Jacobi field $Y$ along the geodesic $t\mapsto \exp_p(tv)$ with initial conditions $Y(0)=v$, $Y'(0)=w$.

Comment: Would you give some pointers of the answer location?